# SQL select inverted tree

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursive-query

Hello i have tree structure in sql. Logics is standard: SomeID, ParentID, other fields.
I have select procedure, which selects data like this:

```
1.
1.1
1.1.1
```

and so on.

How to write the select procedure, to get the inverted result(first are selected the deepest branches, last - root branches), like this:

```
1.1.1.
1.1.
1.
2.2.2.2.2.
2.2.2.2.
2.2.2.
2.2.
2.
```

and so on.

Non inversive select looks like thi(I use SqlServer 2008)s:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Object_SelectDownByRoot]
@ObjectID int

AS
WITH tree (ObjectID, ParentID, ObjectName, ObjectCode, DistrictID, DistrictName, 
                      CityName, RegionName, StreetName, StreetID, AddressID, ObjectTypeName, 
                      RouteName, ObjectTypeID, RouteID, AvrgTempIn, Area, Volume, 
                      ElectricPower, ObjectStatusName, ObjectStatusID, [ControlRoom?], DateBuild, 
                      [Floor], EncloseName, EncloseID, MaintenanceEval, AdministratorID, 
                      Administrator, ElectricityPerson, ElectricityPersonID, 
                      HeatingPersonID, HeatingPerson, HouseNo, FlatNo, ZIP, 
                      AddressStreet, RouteCode, RouteDescription, 
                      AddressDescription, StreetID2, CityID, AddressCityName) AS
    (
        SELECT  
        ObjectID, ParentID, ObjectName, ObjectCode, DistrictID, DistrictName, 
                          CityName, RegionName, StreetName, StreetID, AddressID, ObjectTypeName, 
                          RouteName, ObjectTypeID, RouteID, AvrgTempIn, Area, Volume, 
                          ElectricPower, ObjectStatusName, ObjectStatusID, [ControlRoom?], DateBuild, 
                          [Floor], EncloseName, EncloseID, MaintenanceEval, AdministratorID, 
                          Administrator, ElectricityPerson, ElectricityPersonID, 
                          HeatingPersonID, HeatingPerson, HouseNo, FlatNo, ZIP, 
                          AddressStreet, RouteCode, RouteDescription, 
                          AddressDescription, StreetID2, CityID, AddressCityName
         FROM dbo.[ObjectQ] ofs
         WHERE( ObjectID = @ObjectID )

         UNION ALL

         SELECT     ofs.ObjectID, ofs.ParentID, ofs.ObjectName, ofs.ObjectCode, ofs.DistrictID, ofs.DistrictName, 
                          ofs.CityName, ofs.RegionName, ofs.StreetName, ofs.StreetID, ofs.AddressID, ofs.ObjectTypeName, 
                          ofs.RouteName, ofs.ObjectTypeID, ofs.RouteID, ofs.AvrgTempIn, ofs.Area, ofs.Volume, 
                          ofs.ElectricPower, ofs.ObjectStatusName, ofs.ObjectStatusID, ofs.[ControlRoom?], ofs.DateBuild, 
                          ofs.[Floor], ofs.EncloseName, ofs.EncloseID, ofs.MaintenanceEval, ofs.AdministratorID, 
                          ofs.Administrator, ofs.ElectricityPerson, ofs.ElectricityPersonID, 
                          ofs.HeatingPersonID, ofs.HeatingPerson, ofs.HouseNo, ofs.FlatNo, ofs.ZIP, 
                          ofs.AddressStreet, ofs.RouteCode, ofs.RouteDescription, 
                          ofs.AddressDescription, ofs.StreetID2, ofs.CityID, ofs.AddressCityName
          FROM dbo.[ObjectQ] ofs
          JOIN tree ON tree.ObjectID = ofs.ParentID
    )

    SELECT  
    ObjectID, ParentID, ObjectName, ObjectCode, DistrictID, DistrictName, 
                      CityName, RegionName, StreetName, StreetID, AddressID, ObjectTypeName, 
                      RouteName, ObjectTypeID, RouteID, AvrgTempIn, Area, Volume, 
                      ElectricPower, ObjectStatusName, ObjectStatusID, [ControlRoom?], DateBuild, 
                      [Floor], EncloseName, EncloseID, MaintenanceEval, AdministratorID, 
                      Administrator, ElectricityPerson, ElectricityPersonID, 
                      HeatingPersonID, HeatingPerson, HouseNo, FlatNo, ZIP, 
                      AddressStreet, RouteCode, RouteDescription, 
                      AddressDescription, StreetID2, CityID, AddressCityName
    FROM tree
```

Comment: Could you post the query that you're using to select the regualar (non-inverted) tree? What database are you using? Do a google search on recursive queries, though techniques vary between databases.

Comment: I edited the post and posted the original query

Comment: It might be helpful if you remove the unimportant fields from the original query.  It would clarify where you are getting the 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, etc from.

Comment: Also, it might help if you give a more complex result set that 1's and 2's.  It is confusing how you would handle 1.2.3 etc or if that case even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do recursion then I can only think of one other solution.  I am sure it is not optimal but.  You could do what you are doing above and insert that data into a temp table with 2 extra columns. The one column would hold your parent ID as it seems you are still sorting in descending order on the highest level (since you have all of the 1's before all of the 2's) and the other could just hold a seeded Identity integer.  Then you could just query the table and sort on the original parent ID (the very first number) in ascending order and then the seeded Identity integer in descending order.  From what I gather that would work but it would be inefficient.